# To set dynamic data of excel chart at runtime and not Excel.Range

Tags: c#, excel, charts, series

I want to set data for Excel chart but cannot display data in any Range.
so i cannot use following function :
`chart.SetSourceData(range,XlRowCol)`

i have heared about the series but dont know how to use it
I am having a `List<int> list` of `integers` and want to display a column chart with each integer value on singe column.

Please help me. Any code or suggestions will do.
thnx in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is a List an array? You can assign 1D arrays to the .XValues and .Values of a chart series. You would have to populate multiple series one at a time.