# Chart Data from VBA not Cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

I want to know if it is possible to set the data to a chart from VBA code without having to set it to a bunch of cells.

For the purpose, it can plot anything.. even random numbers. But I don't want to use any cells to paste the values and then do the chart get these values.

[My application has a Sheet with a lot of letters "M" (maintenance), "O" (opperating) and "A" (available), for everyday of the year, from a bunch of equipments. I do some vba filtering on the equipments to get some that I want to plot and want to do some calculations based on the "M", "O" and "A" quantities.]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570023/create-chart-from-array-data-and-not-range

Comment: Yup, certainly possible. To get an idea of how, simply plot a random little chart. Turn on the Macro recorder, then right click the chart to Select Data, and manually type in values separated by commas and see the new chart. Then stop the macro recorder. You'll get a template code ready. (Am using an ipad so can't post code in Answers :) hope it's useful)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
Sub AddChart()
    Dim cht     As Chart
    Dim ser     As Series

    Set cht = Charts.Add
    cht.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    Set ser = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ser.XValues = Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
    ser.Values = Array(2.4, 3.2, 5.7, 12.67)
End Sub
```

You must note that the SERIES formula for a chart in some versions (2003 and prior, I think) is limited to 1024 characters. In 2010, it seems to be limited to 8192 characters. That means that if you use literal values (rather than a range) for the data, each character is included in the formula - so the more decimal places you specify and the more data points, the more likely the code will fail.