# How to stop charts from auto-updating in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that runs a generates a new sheet and populates it with various graphs. The data for these graphs comes from sheet2.  I want to be able to delete sheet2 after generating the graphs without losing all the information in the graphs.  So far I've tried setting  calculations to manual, protecting the sheet, and protecting the charts using both the ProtectData and ProtectSelection methods.  All of the above has failed.  Is there any way using vba to stop charts from changing after they're generated? Thanks.

Edit:
An answer suggested populating an array with values from a range then using that array to generate a chart.  Now I'm running into a type mismatch error when trying to generate the chart.  Is it possible to set the source data equal to an array? Here's my code so far:

```
Dim PlotRangeBar() As Long
Dim PlotRangePie As Variant
Dim XValPie As Variant
Dim XRangeBar As Range
Dim CellCount As Long

'Create bar graph
Set XRangeBar = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B" & DataStart & ":B" & DataEnd)
i = 0
For Row = DataStart To DataEnd
    If Cells(Row, UsedColTimesheet).FormulaR1C1 <> "0" And Cells(Row, UsedColTimesheet) <> vbNullString Then
        ReDim Preserve PlotRangeBar(i)
        PlotRangeBar(i) = Cells(Row, UsedColTimesheet).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        .SetSourceData Source:=PlotRangeBar
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = XRangeBar
        .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleCenteredOverlay)
        .ApplyLayout (1)
        .ChartTitle.Text = ResourceName & " - Hours per project"
        .Legend.Delete
        .ChartStyle = 18
        .ProtectSelection = True
    End With
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to delete sheet2 instead of hiding or very hiding it?

Comment: Sheet2 doesn't necesarily have to be deleted, but all the data does have to be cleared.  This is because if a user wants to generate another sheet with graphs, they will need to paste data into sheet2 because sheet2 is where the program always looks for the data to make the charts. So if a user wanted two sets of graphs that correspond to different sets of data, the data to create the first set of charts cannot exist in sheet2.

Comment: It sounds like this is now a new question.

Comment: Also is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570023/create-chart-from-array-data-and-not-range) now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load your data into an array and use the arrays to load your charts when you create them.

Comment: This is actually what I'm already doing.  The data is loaded into an array, getting the information to populate the array from sheet2, but it seems to make no difference wether the information comes from sheet2 directly or whether it is coming from an array that gets information from sheet2. The information in the charts is still lost when the information in sheet2 is cleared.

Comment: Can you post your code.  You should be able to input only the data in those cells and not a link to the cells themselves.  Somehow you must still be referring to the cells instead of the data when creating the chart.

Comment: Just realized one of my series is a range and not an array.  Changing that should fix it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I thought that loading the data from the range into an array would solve the problem, however I am now running into a problem with setting the source data.  When I try to use ActiveChart.SetSourceData:=someArray I run into a type mismatch error.  I will update the question with some of my code, though now I'm not sure if you can actually set the source data equal to an array?

Comment: @AlexCavanaugh drop the setsource data and change your xvalues to an array of values not a range. Then set your y values like this `.SeriesCollection(1).Values = PlotRangeBar`