# Setting SeriesCollection.Values using variant array

Tags: arrays, excel, charts, excel-2010, vba

I am creating a dashboard of charts in Excel. There is no need for the data to be visible to end users, so I am attempting to use arrays to set SeriesCollection.Values. Here is the offending code block:

```
'test sub to declare and pass header_arr and series_arr
Sub test()

Dim arr1(), arr2() As Variant
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    arr1 = .Range(.Range("I2"), .Range("AI2")).Value
    arr2 = .Range(.Range("I25"), .Range("AI28")).Value
End With

Call CreateWaterfall(arr1, arr2, , , , Range("I30"))

Erase arr1, arr2

End Sub

'sub to create chart
Sub CreateWaterfall(header_arr As Variant, series_arr As Variant, Optional colors As Boolean = True, Optional target_wb = Nothing, Optional target_ws = Nothing, Optional target As Range = Nothing)

'whole bunch of parameter checks that work fine

'trim header_arr
Dim temp() As Variant
ReDim temp(LBound(header_arr, 1) To LBound(header_arr, 1), LBound(header_arr, 2) To UBound(header_arr, 2))
For i = LBound(header_arr, 2) To UBound(header_arr, 2)
    temp(LBound(header_arr, 1), i) = header_arr(1, i)
Next i
ReDim header_arr(LBound(temp, 1) To LBound(temp, 1), LBound(temp, 2) To UBound(temp, 2))
For i = LBound(temp, 2) To UBound(temp, 2)
    header_arr(LBound(temp, 1), i) = temp(LBound(temp, 1), i)
Next i

'declare chart object, start with block...
    '...stuff that works...
For i = 1 To 4
    With .SeriesCollection(i)
        If LBound(series_arr, 1) = 0 Then i = i - 1 'handle base 0 case-operation is reversed at end of loop to avoid incorrect steps
        ReDim temp(LBound(series_arr, 1) To LBound(series_arr, 1), LBound(series_arr, 2) To UBound(series_arr, 2))
        For j = LBound(series_arr, 2) To UBound(series_arr, 2)
            temp(LBound(series_arr, 1), j) = series_arr(i, j)
        Next j
        .Values = temp '<--problem with this line
        .XValues = header_arr
    End With
    If LBound(series_arr, 1) = 0 Then i = i + 1
Next i
'...other stuff that works...
'end with block

End Sub
```

This is within a `With` block that creates the chart and sets its properties. All of the rest of the sub is working properly, even the line here that sets `.XValues`, but none of the `.Values` are correct. When I check them on the spreadsheet itself, they are a series of 0s and #N/As. Checking revealed that this is not because of empty cells in the ranges the arrays are populated form. For the debugging phase I'm in, `series_arr` and `header_arr` are populated using a spreadsheet range; that will not be the case in the final draft. Here is a small example of the kind of data I want the sub to handle (I'm sorry; I don't know how to make it prettier than this...):

215.56  empty  empty  empty  432.73
empty  43.184  empty  56.442  empty
empty  136.65 186.8  345.67  empty
empty  empty  87.653  empty  empty

All the arrays contain the correct data as ascertained by stepping through the code.

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570023/create-chart-from-array-data-and-not-range) already and am stuck; as far as I can tell, the `.Values` line is exactly analogous. I've also used exactly analogous code for other charts with the exception that `.Values` is set using a spreadsheet range, so I know the problem isn't there.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using a 2-dimensional array ? can you share your data ? to simulate the errors you are getting

Comment: What sort of chart is it?

Comment: @Shai Rado `series_arr` and `header_arr` are both two-dimensional, though there is a fail-safe built into the sub in case a user tries to pass an array with more than one row into header_arr. `temp`, however, is one-dimensional. I can't share my data, but it is a range of doubles and empty cells.

@Robin Mackenzie It's a stacked column chart; `.ChartType` is set right after the snippet I posted.

Comment: Could you provide a data range with values something like you're using? How are you representing the empty cells? How is `temp` declared?

Comment: @Jon Peltier done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out myself: it was a variant array vs. array of variants problem. I added some code to force the data within temp when it is used to set `SeriesCollection.Values` into type double. The final block in the snippet I originally posted is now:

```
Dim dbl As Double '<--var to hold contents of series_arr in loop
Dim j As Integer
For i = 1 To 4
    With .SeriesCollection(i)
        If LBound(series_arr, 1) = 0 Then i = i - 1 'handle base 0 case-operation is reversed at end of loop to avoid incorrect steps
        ReDim temp(LBound(series_arr, 2) To UBound(series_arr, 2))
        For j = LBound(series_arr, 2) To UBound(series_arr, 2)
            If series_arr(i, j) = "" Then '<--convert series_arr recs
                temp(j) = 0
            Else
                dbl = series_arr(i, j)
                temp(j) = dbl
            End If
        Next j
        .Values = temp
        .XValues = header_arr
    End With
    If LBound(series_arr, 1) = 0 Then i = i + 1
Next i
```

And it works! Here is my (relatively) educated guess as to why; I would appreciate someone who knows better giving a better answer, though.

Variables of type `Variant` are in principle implicitly convertible to type `Double`, but they are also implicitly convertible to type `String` (among others). This means that `Empty` records are ambiguous; when Excel has to decide to convert it to "" or 0, it needs some other criteria to fall back on.

I thought that the fact that `temp`, when being used to set `.Values`, contained some numbers would cause Excel to convert the `Empty` records to 0, but I guess this isn't the case. My conclusion is that Excel will only convert array elements of type `Variant` to the correct type if *all* of them are convertible to *only* one other type. Thus `header_arr` was correctly converted to type `String`, even when I tested this hypothesis by removing one of the elements of `header_arr`. `series_arr`, on the other hand, since it contained elements that were convertible to type `Double` only but also elements that were convertible to several number types, did not convert properly.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251448.aspx)

Comment: Yep, that's why I was asking about `temp`.