# Create Bar graph with multiple series without the use of Range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if there is a way to write a macro that creates a bar graph with multiple series (depending on the input) without using Range? To get it to work as of now, I have my output written out on a sheet before being able to use it. This feels incredibly unnecessary. Is there an alternative way?

```
Sub CreateBarGraph() 

Set table = Database_U.ListObjects("Table_U") '


Dim ColumnProjektID As String, ColumnVarde As String

Dim Varde As Variant, ProjektID As Variant

ColumnProjektID = "ProjektID"
ColumnVarde = "Varde"

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = GraphSheet

Dim cht As ChartObject

Dim i As Integer
i = 1

For Each currentRow In table.ListRows

   'The return value consist of a name with letters
    Set ProjektID = RetrieveProjektID(currentRow, ColumnProjektID)    
    GraphSheet.Cells(i, 2) = ProjektID

    'The return value consist of a digit/number
    Set Varde = RetrieveVarde(currentRow, ColumnVarde)     
    GraphSheet.Cells(i, 3) = Varde

    i = i + 1

Next


Set cht = GraphSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=20, Width:=800, Top:=20, Height:=500)

Dim rng As range

'1/2 of the below feels like a waste of space. I would like to find a
'way to add the source of the data (and create multiple series) 
'without writing out the values on a sheet

For j = 1 To i
    Set rng = GraphSheet.range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 3))
    cht.chart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=rng
Next i





 End Sub
```

Is there an alternative way to get the same result? Grateful for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Chart from Array data and not range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570023/create-chart-from-array-data-and-not-range)

Comment: I did find that thread as well, but was unfortunately unable to resolve my "issue" based on it

Comment: You can add a new series using SeriesCollection.NewSeries
 and then set it's value to the array

Comment: @TinMan, .NewSeries with a ChartObject or with what kind? I spent long trying to get it to work with that (and also with an array). I declared an array with "()" and a Redim statement and added the function output into it with many problems. I think I however managed to get it to work with a "CSTR"  on my function output (that extract values from my Table), but I was unable to assign the values in the array to the graph. If I recall, it was some issue with creating a new series for every new input in the array

Comment: Also, ideally (since I also have a color code with the input from a third function) it would be great if I could add a series with every loop

Answer (score 1):

A **ChartObject** is basically a Shape that wraps a **Chart**.  You need to add a **NewSeries** to the **SeriesCollection** of the Chart contained within the **ChartObject**.

Short Code

> ```
> ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = Array(10, 5, 21, 54, 76, 12)
> ```

Demo

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ChartObject As ChartObject
    Dim Chart As Chart

    Set ChartObject = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
    Set Chart = ChartObject.Chart

    Dim Series As Series
    Set Series = Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    Series.Values = Array(10, 5, 21, 54, 76, 12)

End Sub
```

Here is how you can format the Series
        'Color the Line
        Series.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
        'Color the Interior Fill
        Series.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbMagenta

### Addendum

You can assign an array of Category Names like this:

```
Dim Axis As Axis
Set Axis = Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
Axis.CategoryNames = myArray2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I still have to modify it further ( which is the part I don't quite understand)  to get it to work for my purpose. For example, would ___ For j= 1 to i .... Series.values = myArray(i) work? Where a loop then adds a new series, assigns a name, and a value for each "cycle?

Comment: Or, If I could just store let say 10 values (integer) in one array, 10 values (names) in another array. Could I then add 10 series right away? The idea is that the value i belongs to the name j, and value i +1 belongs to name j+1 (array index). This would actually be even greater:)

Comment: cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = myArray2
cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = myArray                                               This works (data and name of the bar graphs), but only 1 series is created

Comment: @OmgAllCaps The array of categories are stored in the Axes collection of the chart.  chat.Axes(xlCategories).Values = ArrayOfNames might do it.

Comment: xlCategories doesn't exist, right? I get "variable undefined" and "cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).Values = myArray2" gives me an error "Run-time error '438' - Object doesn't support this property or method. :/

Comment: @OmgAllCaps  I edited my answer to show the proper syntax.

Comment: I tried using the edited code. With the code I have, I created 5 bars with 5 legends (the bars show the correct numeric values and legend contain the correct names), but underneath my 5 bar graphs it just say number "1". Upon running your code, the number "1" changed name to the first value in myArray2. So it seems to be working, but my error is probably deeper.. I'll open up a new question in a few minutes and close this one (I think that would be better so it better reflect the progress I have made). I'll also add pictures. Thank you!